# Java KeyStore jks as certificate authority

Tags: java, openssl

I'm converting an old app that uses openssl to Java.  I was wondering if there was any downside in using Java's KeyStore as a certificate authority. Like is there any performance loss in using Java's Keystore or any limit on the number of clients' certs that I can store in a Java Keystore?  I want to eventually implement 2 way SSL where the client authenticates and the server knows which clients are allowed to talk to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was any downside in using Java's KeyStore as a certificate authority.

You're not using it as a certificate authority. A Certificate Authority is a trusted entity - a *company* - that signs certificates. A keystore is a file that stores public/private key pairs, signed certificates, and trusted certificates. Don't misuse terminology.

> Like is there any performance loss in using Java's Keystore

Compared to what? It's a pretty pointless question when the only alternative is a PKCS#12 keystore, which is also a file, and when both are loaded into memory, and when the performance characteristics of either aren't rate-determining steps in the first place.

> or any limit on the number of clients' certs that I can store in a Java Keystore?

No.

Comment: Sorry, I meant as our own CA to sign certs for clients.

Comment: Well that makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. It's a file, not a tool. Are you referring to the `keytool`? But if so the questions about performance don't make sense either.